# PurePDF - best way to add good quality snapshot of a display object

Tags: apache-flex, pdf

Anyone have any experience with PurePDF and adding a display object to the page? In AlivePDF, you do something like this:

```
pdfObject.addImage(yourDisplayObject,...)
```

where yourDisplayObject is a class that inherits from DisplayObject. AlivePDF internally takes care of converting this into an image and adding the image to the pdf page.

What would be the equivalent of this for purePDF?

Any purePDF experts out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use PurePDF.  This code will take an object like UIComponent, turn it into a bitmap and put it in your pdf.

```
var matrix : Matrix = new Matrix();
var pageSize:RectangleElement = PageSize.A4;
var mainImage : BitmapData = new BitmapData(_objectToPrint.width,_objectToPrint.height,false, 0xFFFFFF);
mainImage.draw(_objectToPrint,matrix);

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var document:PdfDocument = PdfWriter.create(bytes, pageSize).pdfDocument;
document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
document.open();
var imageElement : ImageElement = ImageElement.getBitmapDataInstance(mainImage, false);
document.add(imageElement);
document.close();
new FileReference().save(bytes,"yourPDF.pdf");
```